# Don't use SUBSTRING_INDEX if 3rd param is NULL

Tags: mysql, substring

I've got a news script which cuts news by paragraphs on the main page. I want users to enter a number after which paragraph the news should be cut. That number is is also stored in the database.

My current code:

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(newsText, "\n", newsShortbreaks + 1)`

Users should also be able to show the whole text by leaving that field blank. Problem: there's still only one parahraph because NULL + 1 = 1.

Does anyone has a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to use in your select/update/insert to following structure:

```
if(newsShortbreaks is not null, SUBSTRING_INDEX(newsText, "\n", newsShortbreaks + 1), newsText)
```

so in case when `newsShortbreaks =null` you get just newsText.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` inside a [case statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) and only take a substring when some parameter is not null.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN @newsShortbreaks IS NOT NULL 
         THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(newsText, "\n", @newsShortbreaks + 1) 
         ELSE newsText 
    END

FROM MyTable
```

I only have an MS SQL Server instance handy at the moment but I believe this general approach will work in MySql.

[Here is a MySql-specific example.](http://blog.cnizz.com/2007/11/08/mysql-case-statement/)

Comment: +1'd this, but I will use ravnur's way, because of shortness. Thanks!